# How to import a class from web server

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an swf file that is stored on my local device and I want it to import a class (.as file) from a webserver (ex:http://webserver.com/com/myClass.as).
How can I do that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that you can import an online class as far as I know. Why can't you download the class and then use it?

Comment: @GurtejSingh I'm designing a website using just flash (as3). At the main page there is just one main swf file and I want this file to import other classes from the same web server. Anyway is there a way to merge all classes inside one swf file instead of importing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class files cannot be executed.

There's no such thing as "importing" a class file at runtime, because the class has to be compiled first before being used (and importing happens during compile time).

What you can do is compile your classes into an .swf file and then load these .swf files at runtime from the server.

> I'm designing a website using just flash (as3).

Even before the whole html5 vs flash debate this was a bad idea in general.

Please verify that you are using the appropriate tools for the task. For certain scenarios it might be reasonable to do a falsh-only website, but these are very rare.